# Skip test if BeforeSuite did not run

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, testng

I am having a look into TestNG for more complex tests. It might easily be that I am just doing it wrong.

My setup:

I am running tests in Intellij (latest) using the TestNG runner. I don't use a custom testng.xml file.

**Class A**: Does not contain actual tests but only `@BeforeSuite(groups="groupA")` and `@AfterSuite(groups="groupA")` annotated methods for the setup of a static variable I want to use in the actual test classes.

**Class B**: Contains a single `@Test(dependsOnGroups = "groupA")` annotated test method.

My goal: Only execute the test in Class B if Class A has also been run.
My issue: Even if I run both classes, the test in Class B is skipped.

My thinking: The `@BeforeSuite(groups="groupA")` annotated method should be executed before the test in Class B, so I thought, that the dependency on `groupA` would be satisfied.

My question: It seems not to. Why?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter if you don't use testng.xml IntelliJ do it for you.

Let's assume you have:

```
public class ClassA {

    @Test(dependsOnGroups = "groupA")
    public void test1(){
        System.out.println("test in groupA");
    }
}

public class ClassB {

    @BeforeSuite(groups = "groupA")
    public void beforeSuite() {
        System.out.println("before suite in group A");
    }

    @AfterSuite(groups = "groupA")
    public void afterSuite() {
        System.out.println("after suite in group A");
    }

}
```

If you try to run specific method, class or suite you will fail with execption that is because generated xml will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Default Suite">
  <test name="TestNG-Examples">
    <classes>
      <class name="suite.ClassA">
        <methods>
          <include name="test1"/>
        </methods>
      </class> <!-- suite.ClassA -->
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- TestNG-Examples -->
</suite> <!-- Default Suite -->
```

But if you will try to run group using run configuration from IDE the following xml will be generated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Custom suite" parallel="none">
  <test verbose="1" name="TestNG-Examples">
    <groups>
      <run>
        <include name="groupA"/>
      </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
      <class name="suite.ClassA"/>
      <class name="suite.ClassB"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- TestNG-Examples -->
</suite> <!-- Custom suite -->
```